# New Activity intent onClick in viewPager Slides

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager

Below is my Code.
Using ViewPager I have made 2 XML file for two Pages and their Class file.

Now I need if I click on First Screen of ViewPager, a new activity should launch.

I got 2 pages, so If I Click First Screen, A.class intent Called. If I click on Second Screen, B.class intent should be Called.

Codes:-

MainActvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
/** set the adapter for ViewPager */
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

/** Defining a FragmentPagerAdapter class for controlling the fragments to       
be shown when user swipes on the screen. */
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */
        if (position == 0) {
            return new SampleFragment();
        } else
            return new SampleFragmentTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

SampleFragment.java

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
    return rootView;
    }
    }
```

SampleFragmentTwo.java

```
public class SampleFragmentTwo extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

CustomSwipeAdapter:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}


}
```

Comment: you can set listener on your `rootView` and start activity from it

Comment: you mean, in FragmentOne class, I've to set OnClickListener for Intent?

Comment: i guess no, the swipe and click listener together won't give you the desired result , you can create some view like button or something to open a new activity

Comment: can you please tell me where should I change my code to set onClick. coz i am using fragment so there is no scope of onCreate in my SampleFragment.class

Comment: simply google about use views or button in fragments , lot of tutorials out there

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, In your fragment classes A and B put onClick listener on views and launch intent from there like below:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
      rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked 
        Intent activityA = new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(activityA);

       }
      return rootView;
    }
  }
```

similarlly goes for your second fragment.

Comment: anyways thanks, I've fixed the Issue by other method